# Attaching documents to Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am making a list on Sharepoint Online, and every item on the list will have a document or image Associated With it. So, my client wants to be able to upload documents and/or images to the list when creating items. Does any column type allow me to do that?

If not, what are some possible work-arounds or alternatives? (my Client needs the documents to be readily available and accessible through the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In List Settings you can enable Attachments.

List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Enable Attachments

Then you will be able to attach files to list items.